# Selecting all the links

Tags: jquery, html

How would you select all the links inside a certain div, using `jquery`?

```
<div id="content">
     
    <!-- SELECT ALL LINKS IN THIS DIV -->
     
    <a href="mysite.com">My site</a>
    <a href="mysite.com">Link 2</a>
     
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <a href="alink.com">Don't select any links from this div</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lee, the problem with that, is that if you have an anchor, you will be selecting it too..

Have you noticed how you could this too? It's a bit safer I would say...

```
$('#content a[href]')
```

In case you had a simple anchor you wouldn't want selected..

Comment: the OP's use of the word "links" is ambiguous -- I took it to mean "all `<a>` elements".  You make a good point though, if he doesn't want to catch non-link anchor definitions as well, then your example is the way to go (+1 for multiple perspectives).

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#content a')
```

where `content` is the `id` of the `<div>` that holds the `<a>` elements that you want to select.